# Is there a way to create a bubble chart with Chartist.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chartist.js

I'm searching for a chart tool to integrate into my app and I really liked the Chartist.js but I couldn't found any resources showing how to create bubble charts like [this one in D3](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269).

My goal is to create a non-overlapping bubble chart with images.

I would like to know if there is a way to achieve this natively or with a plugin.